# Bluetooth Audio issue with new Beats Wireless Studio 3 headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

I recently bought a new [Beats Studio 3 Wireless](https://www.beatsbydre.com/headphones/studio3-wireless) headphones and connected them with my Lenovo Yoga X1 3rd gen notebook with Windows 10 and latest build 1803. Devices are normally paired, playing sound works.

Issue is with my new Beats headphones over Bluetooth when some/any application uses input audio device (microphone), microphone works, but at that time, no audio output is working on new headphones. So basically I am unable to do Skype call etc. (tried other apps, also tried recording from microphone while listening YouTube music...). It never worked correctly.

1) I have tried to visit Apple support center, and have case number opened with Apple. Basically on Android, and iPhone devices, including MacBook it works normally.
Also I have tried another / new Headphones and also Beats Solo 3 model at the store, but the same issue.
Officially speaking, under web and supported devices, it says generally that it works with "any bluetooth device" which can have hands free (meaning also Windows 10 etc.)
Firmware update is at latest.

2) I have tried on newer and older computers , desktop and notebooks, various vendors, HP, Dell and Lenovo, and different Bluetooth adapters and their firmware. Tried on Windows 10 Pro build 1803 and older. Tried on a new computer with no additional software. Tried different Default device or default communication device combinations. Always the same issue. When I am using cable (3.5mm connection) everything is fine (sound goes through Realtek sound card and is ok).

3) I have tried my old, and any other Headphones over Bluetooth that I could find, and they work fine (only one playback/recording audio device)

(hp-toster is my name for the device)

[image: Playback Audio devices]

**Having one shown as "Hands-free" and another as "Stereo". The one with "Hands-free" never works or outputs the sound. This is only with this headphones, and could be a reason / problem for this issue.**

Generally, I need some experience / advice. **Does anybody have Beats studio with Windows 10 and is doing something like Skype calls over bluetooth?** What else, could I try / test to troubleshoot why it does not work.

On microphone side it is simple.

[image: Recording Audio devices]

Also, if I am listening music, and just try to switch to recording tab (microphone VU-meter works, windows is using microphone, but music stops playing)

Any concrete help would be appreciated.
Basically I am unable to blame / have warranty with Headphones (they work on other systems) nor my device (other headphones works), nor Microsoft. Maybe only Apple / Beats should write on their website that Windows 10 is not supported, which they say also via email case, that it is supported and works.

To conclude, handsfree playback never ever works in my cases.
Tried also have one bluetooth service active. All drivers are native from Microsoft / default drivers from year 2018.

[image: Bluetooth services]

Comment: Yours is the second or third similar question about the same headphones so maybe there's really something to it. However, even considering that Beats product are just polished turds with a celebrity endorsement, I find it hard to believe they don't work for something as basic as this. Let's try troubleshooting: First of all make sure you're using HFP (hands-free profile) for Skype or any other software requiring the microphone. That done please check Skype's audio settings have the HF handset selected as output. Make a test call. If it doesn't work then perhaps it needs a firmware update.

Comment: I will be honest.  Your question is extremely hard to read.  You have supplied us a lot of information, that does not clarify the problem you face, but it sounds like while the device is set to be the default audio device (within Windows) the application is set to a different audio device.  This is a configuration issue, the device in question is 100% compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound *the device in question is 100% compatible with Windows 10*. That's what I thought this morning but now I'm not so sure. Multiple users reporting the exact same issue with the exact same obscenely overpriced polished turd warrants a closer look. It must be said though that the other users were doing the opposite of what should be done, but not the case with the OP of this question.

Comment: It's a Bluetooth audio device.  I don't see how it could not be compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: I have provided lot of information to avoid lot of comments, and to speedup troubleshooting. I am aware of Default playback audio device options/settings etc. As I said, other Bluetooth headphones are working correctly on the same Win10 devices. Also does somebody have this headphones that are working on win10? Again, I believe that main issue is why there are two Playback devices (stereo and handsfree), where handsfree never works. It is not up to (Skype) application, also in OS / this sound contro panel does not work (when using mic / vu-meter / test, playback is not working).

Comment: Also, can you reference me links to same questions for same headsets so I can forward to Apple support.

Comment: @Ramhound I also do not know how it could not work. Anyhow, do you know someone who has win10 and any Beats bluetooth product where hand-free mode works? simple - yes/no ?

Comment: still, I am unable to find Bluetooth adapter, which works correctly with the Win10 and those Beats headphones, issue still persits

Comment: A workaround I encountered once was to disable the Hands-Free playback and recording device in Control Panel > Sounds. In the Playback and Recording tabs right-click the 'Headset, xxxx Hands-Free' device and Disable.

Comment: @harrymc thank you, that has also worked for me to temporarily activate the sound again, at least until an app tries to access the mic again (and I have to enable it to disable it again)... But that still does not fix the issue that the mic and sound cannot work simultaneously on Windows.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was somewhere within Bluetooth adapter/driver on Windows 10 side. Same error was happening for some other bluetooth headsets (but some were working fine).

Anyhow, after upgrade to Windows 10, build 1809, bluetooth hands-free and playback device are working correctly (and auto switching for stereo playback and hands-free microphone and playback during use of microphone / Skype / Microsoft Teams or others).